# multiple where statement mongodb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Ok so i'm having a hard time with mongodb, coming from MySQL i'm having trouble
writing the queries to get my data. My Database looks like this:

```
opened: [
            {day: "Monday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Thuesday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Wednesday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Thursday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Friday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Saturday", from: 64800, till: 79200},
            {day: "Sunday", from: 64800, till: 79200}
        ]
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is the following:
I have a variable named: currendTime and I have a variable where I have the currentDay as a full name. So the variable currentDay contains "Friday".

What I want to achieve is to search for the day where currentDay is equal to Friday and where current time is higher than "from" and currentTime is lower than "till"

Could somebody help me?

**Update**
this is what i have so far:

```
db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(
        {
            opened: {$and: [{$elemMatch: {day: weekDay}}, 
                            {from: {$lt: currentTime}},
                            {till: {$gt: currentTime}}]}
            }).toArray(function(err,items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked out the docs on translating SQL concepts into MongoDB? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/#select

Comment: I have, and this is what I came up with:
    **check above **
however it returns nothing :(

**Ill add the code above ^^ **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine all the array element fields to match against into the `$elemMatch` object:

```
db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({
        opened: {
            $elemMatch: {
                day: weekDay, 
                from: {$lt: currentTime},
                till: {$gt: currentTime}
            }
        }
    }).toArray(function(err,items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
```

If you just want that matched element, include the following field projection parameter to your `find` call:

```
{ 'opened.$': 1 }
```